# Effect of KH on Neocaridina shrimp

Tags: aquarium, freshwater, water-parameters, invertebrates, shrimp

It is my understanding that, in the aquarium, KH (carbonate hardness) raises the pH slightly, but primarily acts as a "buffer", preventing large pH swings.  For *Neocaridina* shrimp (I keep red cherries, but I suppose for any *Neocaridina*s) I have seen recommended KH levels from anywhere between 0 to 3.  Though, most common is probably 1-2.  However, I read that several very successful shrimp breeders don't supplement their RO water with any KH whatsoever, using only GH+ remineralizers.

What are the pros and cons of forgoing the addition of KH to *Neocaridina* tanks?  It does give you the opportunity to add other KH sensitive species like Tigers or Bees (shrimp species, not cats or insects), but are there any other benefits?  Are there any cons besides having a less stable pH?  Why is having a less stable pH not a concern for these breeders?

Comment: Sorry for sneaking in several questions, but I feel like a solid answer would probably cover everything.